# Forbid system to change orientation

Tags: orientation

I recently "upgraded" against my will from Oreo to Pie, and a problem that wasn't there came up:

I have apps that fine control the orientation: [Rotation Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.crape.rotationcontrol), and Tasker (they don't fight).

But every time I turn off the screen for a little while, the system overrides my apps and the phone is back to portrait!

Any way to **FORBID** Android to do that ?

I also noticed an orientation-related animated icon on the corner, next to the app history button, when the screen orientation is in disaccord to the accelerometer. This clearly indicates that Android added a (stupid) feature.

Rooted

I believe the solution might be to prevent system to see the state of the accelerometer, but without compromising everything else.

.

Hated this Pie ! Not only has this problem, as it also overrides my screen brightness. And they completely misorganized the settings and the volume menu from the previous version.

Comment: Rotation Control works fine for me, and I'm on a stock device?  Or do you mean you don't want AOD to change orientation?  I'd suggest checking out your system values via SetEdit, though I'm not sure if it's due to lack of root or not but disabling Accelerometer-Rotation didn't disable system-side rotation, you might have better luck.  Also there's a rotation lock accessibility feature, might be worth taking a look.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. The rotation is DISABLED on the accessibility, but the thing (Android) rotates anyway: I set REVERSE on Rotation Control app, I turn off screen, and the thing goes back portrait. It's not a modded system. Default Pie Android. I wouldn't like to disable the accelerometer. It's like crippling the phone to work around a problem that shouldn't be there in the first place...